# Eclipse WTP: Remove tomcat specific jar from build path

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, eclipse-wtp

I use **Eclipse WTP** and **Apache Tomcat** for developing web applications.
To build portable applications and see unwanted dependencies early, I'd like to **remove tomcat specific jars** (e.g. `tomcat-dbcp.jar`, `tomcat-jdbc.jar` etc.) from build path.

Unfortunately, I was not able to do so (tried project specific preferences, 
`Java build path -> Libraries -> Apache Tomcat`, however, I'm not able to delete ***specific jars***).

**Is this possible somehow**?

Answer (score 0):

No, because those jars are part of the Tomcat 8 installation itself and provided as part of the classpath to anything you're running within it, whether Tomcat is launched by Eclipse or not. Use the J2EE Preview Server in the project's `Java Build Path` if you only want the minimal amount contributed during development; you should still be able to launch it within the Tomcat instance.

Comment: Sounds good - but how can I assign a specific JRE to the "J2EE Preview Server"? It seems that it always uses the default JRE which major version does not match the one I'm using in the particular project.

Comment: How do you figure it's using a different JRE from the project's? Using it for what?

Comment: My default/platform JRE is 1.7. I created a "J2EE Preview Server"  server runtime. I'm not able to assign this runtime to a JRE 1.8 project (it's not in the list, greyed out when "showing all runtimes") while I can do this for a JRE 1.7 project. When changing the Java version in the "Project Facets" tab from 1.8 to 1.7, the "J2EE Preview Server" runtime suddenly appears.